Euler-Lagrange equations for fields
I am following the discussion presented on Hobson's book "General Relativity: An Introduction for Physicists" where he deduct the Euler-Lagrange equation for fields and I am stuck in a mathematical problem:
$$\int_R \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_{\mu}\Phi^a)}\partial_{\mu}(\delta\Phi^a)d^4x = \int_R\partial_{\mu}\left[\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_{\mu}\Phi^a)}\delta\Phi^a\right]d^4x - \int_R \partial_{\mu}\left[\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_{\mu}\Phi^a)}\right]\delta\Phi^ad^4x,$$
and he said that by integrating by parts the left side we achieve the right side, but I don't understand how to do this integration by parts, could someone help me?

Is your question: what is integration by parts? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts

Let's see. To show how to derive the right-hand side from the left-hand side using integration by parts, let's first clearly write down the integral we need to manipulate:
$$ \int_R \frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial_\mu \Phi^a)} \partial_\mu (\delta \Phi^a) \, d^4x $$
We aim to integrate this by parts. The idea behind integration by parts in multiple dimensions is similar to the one-dimensional case: we transfer the derivative from one term to another and include a boundary term. Here, we'll use the following form of the integration by parts formula in the context of fields:
$$ \int_R \partial_\mu (A^\mu) \, d^4x = \int_{\partial R} A^\mu \, dS_\mu $$
where $\partial R$ is the boundary of the region $R$ and $dS_\mu$ is the boundary measure.
Step-by-Step Integration by Parts

Identify $u$ and $v$: In the given integral, we can identify:
$$
   u = \frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial_\mu \Phi^a)}, \quad v = \partial_\mu (\delta \Phi^a)
   $$

Apply the Divergence Theorem:
To integrate by parts, we use the product rule for divergence in higher dimensions. Specifically, we consider:
$$
   \partial_\mu \left( u \cdot v \right) = (\partial_\mu u) \cdot v + u \cdot (\partial_\mu v)
   $$
Here, $u \cdot v$ is a scalar product.
Applying this to our integrand, we get:
$$
   \partial_\mu \left( \frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial_\mu \Phi^a)} \delta \Phi^a \right) = \partial_\mu \left( \frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial_\mu \Phi^a)} \right) \delta \Phi^a + \frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial_\mu \Phi^a)} \partial_\mu (\delta \Phi^a)
   $$

Rearrange the Integral:
We can now write the original integral as:
$$
   \int_R \frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial_\mu \Phi^a)} \partial_\mu (\delta \Phi^a) \, d^4x = \int_R \partial_\mu \left( \frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial_\mu \Phi^a)} \delta \Phi^a \right) \, d^4x - \int_R \left( \partial_\mu \left( \frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial_\mu \Phi^a)} \right) \delta \Phi^a \right) \, d^4x
   $$

Boundary Term:
The first term on the right side is a total divergence. By the divergence theorem, this term can be converted to a surface integral over the boundary $\partial R$:
$$
   \int_R \partial_\mu \left( \frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial_\mu \Phi^a)} \delta \Phi^a \right) \, d^4x = \int_{\partial R} \frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial_\mu \Phi^a)} \delta \Phi^a \, dS_\mu
   $$
If the variations $\delta \Phi^a$ vanish on the boundary (a common assumption in field theory to simplify calculations), this surface term will be zero:
$$
   \int_{\partial R} \frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial_\mu \Phi^a)} \delta \Phi^a \, dS_\mu = 0
   $$

Final Result:
We are left with:
$$
   \int_R \frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial_\mu \Phi^a)} \partial_\mu (\delta \Phi^a) \, d^4x = - \int_R \partial_\mu \left( \frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial_\mu \Phi^a)} \right) \delta \Phi^a \, d^4x
   $$


This shows how the integration by parts works in this context and achieves the desired result:
$$ \int_R \frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial_\mu \Phi^a)} \partial_\mu (\delta \Phi^a) \, d^4x = \int_R \partial_\mu \left( \frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial_\mu \Phi^a)} \delta \Phi^a \right) d^4x - \int_R \partial_\mu \left( \frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial_\mu \Phi^a)} \right) \delta \Phi^a d^4x $$
Thus, the left-hand side can be transformed into the right-hand side by integration by parts.
